# Dynamic fields in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How do you create dynamic fields in a SQL Server table?  I'd like to add this to the create table command:

```
isDeleted = CASE WHEN DeleteDate is null THEN 0 ELSE 1
```

Comment: No I want it in the table itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking to create a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx).

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (
    ...
    isDeleted AS CASE WHEN DeleteDate IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
);
```

Comment: isClubDeleted AS CASE WHEN ClubDelDate is null THEN 0 ELSE 1  is giving me an error.

Comment: @cf_PhillipSenn, you need to `END` the `CASE`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean by dynamic field, but I think this is what you're asking for:

```
SELECT    MyTable.Foo,
          CASE WHEN MyTable.Foo = "FOO" THEN
              0
          ELSE
              1
          END AS isDeleted
FROM      MyTable
```